# Short story about a man who lands on Mars, and Martians don't believe he's from Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In my childhood, I read a short story about a man who lands on Mars and finds that Martians looked exactly like humans. When he told them he was from Earth, everyone thought he had a disease that makes him hallucinate. So he takes some Martians to see his space ship, and they think they caught that disease from him. He's later sent to a hospital/asylum where he meets martians who really had that disease. Unfortunately, I don't remember how it ended.

Comment: Roughly speaking, when was your childhood, or when would you estimate that you read it? Do you recall if it was in an anthology book, or a magazine, or something else?

Comment: Yes, it was in an anthology of science fiction stories, but that's the only story I remember from it. I read it in the 90s, but it was probably older than that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems to be the story *The Earth Men*, part of the [Martian Chronicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Chronicles) bundle of short stories by Ray Bradbury. From Wikipedia:

> This story tells of the "Second Expedition" to Mars. The expedition is
>   a group of 4 men. The astronauts arrive to find the Martians to be
>   strangely unresponsive to their presence. The one exception to this is
>   a group of Martians in a building who greet them with a parade.
>   Several of the Martians in the building claim to be from Earth or from
>   other planets of the solar system, and the captain slowly realizes
>   that the Martian gift for telepathy allows others to view the
>   hallucinations of the insane, and that they have been placed in an
>   insane asylum. The Martians they have encountered all believed that
>   their unusual appearance was a projected hallucination. Because the
>   "hallucinations" are so detailed and the captain refuses to admit he
>   is not from Earth, Mr. Xxx, a psychiatrist, declares him incurable and
>   kills him. When the "imaginary" crew does not disappear as well, Mr.
>   Xxx shoots and kills them too. Finally, as the "imaginary" rocket
>   remains in existence, Mr. Xxx concludes that he too must be crazy and
>   shoots himself. The ship of the Second Expedition is sold as scrap at
>   a junkyard.

Comment: Bradbury was such a storytelling genius... Now I need to go reread all of him

Comment: I concur.  The next story is even more chilling -- the one where the Terran crew is met by their long-lost (dead) parents, lovers, etc.

Comment: OP's story seems so much more whimsical and fantastical compared to the morbid tragedy what you describe.

Comment: Yes! That's the one! And @cde, I blame childhood innocence.

Comment: @imgx64 now I want someone to write a comedy based on your initial description. Throw some slapstick in to boot.